# pass parameters in api js

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, server

I need to pass login and email to const validateUser but i dont know how i can do it

```
import { UserEntityModel } from './model';
const port: string = '3000';
const baseUrl: string = `http://localhost:${port}`;
const usersUrl: string = `${baseUrl}/users`;
```

Here i pass the login and email

```
export const validateUserInDB = ({login, email}: UserEntityModel): Promise<boolean> => {
 return fetch(usersUrl)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(resolveUsers)
  .then(validateUser);
};
```

...

And i need to use it here

```
const validateUser = (data)  => {
  const userProfile = data.find((profile) =>
    profile.login.toUpperCase() === this.login.toUpperCase() ||
    profile.email.toUpperCase() === this.email.toUpperCase());
  return (userProfile !== void (0) && userProfile !== null);
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain your ask in text? For more details, take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you will be able to pass and use login/email like this:

```
export const validateUserInDB = ({login, email}: UserEntityModel): Promise<boolean> => {

 return fetch(usersUrl)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(resolveUsers)
  .then(data => validateUser(data, {login, email})); // pass login/email explicitly
};

const validateUser = (data, {login, email})  => {
  const userProfile = data.find((profile) =>
    profile.login.toUpperCase() === login.toUpperCase() ||
    profile.email.toUpperCase() === email.toUpperCase());

  return (userProfile !== void (0) && userProfile !== null);
};
```

Or maybe event without destructuring `.then(data => validateUser(data, login, email));` whatever you prefer.

Comment: @GerardLópezSorribas You are welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped :)